# Why does list.insert[-1] not work in python?

Tags: python

I have searched and found how to get the insert to the last on list but I am now curious as to why [-1] does not work.

Comment: Why would you expect that to work? If you tell us why you expected it to work, we can explain what you've misunderstood.

Comment: Sorry just realized I used brackets and im very new to asking question and everything.

Ok so i have 
games = []
games.append ('skyrim')
games.append ('gta5')
games.insert (-1, american truck simulator)

But this adds american truck simulator to the second from last in the list. I did figure out how to add to the last but now I want to know why the games.insert (-1, american truck simulator) doesnt work.

Comment: `list.insert` takes two arguments - the index at which you want to insert an object, and the object to be inserted. Also, the use of square brackets isn't right.  Try `my_list.insert(3, 'apples')`.

Comment: Also having trouble formatting the text here as well it seems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3]
```

and you do

```
some_list.insert(-1, 4)
```

You might think, "okay, -1 means the last index, so it'll insert 4 at the last index". But the last index is index 2, over here:

```
[1, 2, 3]
#      ^
```

It'll insert 4 at *that* index, producing

```
[1, 2, 4, 3]
#      ^ 4 inserted here
```

You don't want 4 to end up at the current last index. You want to insert 4 at index 3, an index that isn't even in the list yet. You could do that with

```
some_list.insert(3, 4)
```

but it's clearer to do

```
some_list.append(4)
```

Comment: AHHH, I now see what it was trying to do!! Thanks so much. You see I had figured out how to get it there but I wanted to learn WHY what i just learned about -1 wasnt going to work in this case. Again thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

[`list.append(element)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=append) is what you are looking for `list[-1]` is [notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation#509295) for *accessing* the last element

Comment: `list[-1]` is just regular indexing. No slices involved.

Comment: Yes list.append(element) works just fine but say I have a large list that I want to add to the end of. Im just curious as to why list.insert(-1, element) wont add to end of that list.

Comment: Because adding to position `-1` is adding at the `len(list) - 1` position, or one before the end. Click the first link to see the equivalent `insert` usage from the documentation

Answer (score -1):

```
# Python Program for array rotation


def array_rotation(array, r, d):
    for item in range(r):
        element = array.pop(-d)
        if d:     # -------------------------------->does left to right rotation
            array.insert(d-1, element)
        else:     # -------------------------------->does right to left rotation
            array.append(element)
    return array


arr = ['10', '20', '30', '40', '50']

rotations = input('Enter number of rotations to make in array: ')
direction = input('Enter the direction for rotation:\n1 for right_to_left rotation\n2 for left_to_right rotation\n')
print(arr)
print(array_rotation(arr, int(rotations), 0 if direction == '1' else 1))
```